# Intellij IDEA complains cannot resolve spring boot properties but they work fine

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, application.properties

[image]

> Can not resolve configuration property '...

I have no problem accessing my properties through the @Value annotation or through an autowired Evironment. But all of my own defined properties get this warning in IDEA. What should I be doing to get IDEA to recognize these and not bother me?

Comment: Don't worry about it; IntelliJ has a  bit of a time recognizing custom properties anyway.  At best you could file a bug with JetBrains.

Comment: You could check which facets are associated with your project. Try ctrl + alt + shift + s, and look for facets. You might have to manually add a spring (boot) facet for intellij to understand..

Comment: I added the spring facet and there was no change. But I do not have Spring(boot) facet in my list. Maybe because I am on a 2016 version of IDEA.

Comment: Is it possible to provide sample project example for investigation?

Comment: try installing Spring Assistant plugin.

Comment: This problem persists in intellij 2021.1. I am just going to ignore it.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

In order for IntelliJ IDEA to know your Spring Boot properties, you can define **Spring Boot configuration metadata** in your project.

#### Option 1:

If you can use a `@ConfigurationProperties`-annotated class for your properties, you can add the Spring Boot configuration annotation processor to your classpath and IntelliJ IDEA will generate the configuration metadata for you in `target` or `out`:

**Maven:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle:**

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
```

#### Option 2:

Create the configuration metadata file yourself `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json`:

Content:

```
{
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "myapp.someprop",
      "type": "java.lang.String"
    },
    {
      "name": "myapp.someintprop",
      "type": "java.lang.Integer"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Options 1 and 2:

In the IntelliJ IDEA tool window of your build system (Maven/Gradle), click the "Refresh" button.

Select `Build > Rebuild Project` from the menu.

If the warning still appears, you can try to restart the IDE. Select `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` and click on `Invalidate and Restart`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!  I went with option 2!

Comment: FYI. Spring Reference > Appendix B. Configuration Metadata : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html

Comment: Select Build > Rebuild Project from the menu had fixed my issue

Comment: I wrote properties in applicaition.property and use in dependency(other jar). Can it works?

Comment: I strongly recommend to use option 1 (`@ConfigurationProperties` and annotation processor), since it saves you tedious and error-prone handwriting of meta data files. And, after the initial setup, it is even easier to use than `@Value` annotations.

Comment: I suggest removing this ridiculous warning at the root: IntelliJ itself.  My properties are DEFINITIONS so why is the IDEA complaining that the thing I am DEFINING does not exist? Do I really need to resort to more meta-data friction, cost and complexity just to suppress an unnecessary warning?

Comment: @Namo link is broken, I think new one is [Configuring the Annotation Processor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.1/reference/html/appendix-configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor-setup).

Comment: Option 2 is nice because it allows you to specify descriptions that actually tell what those configuration fields are for. It can be really helpful instead of needing to declare that information somewhere else like Confluence or within the README.

Comment: Still does not help with Kotlin projects. The same configuration with `@ConfigurationProperties` is working perfectly in the Java project, without any additional IntelliJ setup. For Kotlin project, nothing is helping :(

Answer (score 4):

Please use the following for Gradle Kotlin Script for Kotlin project:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("kapt")
}

/* ... */

dependencies {
    val configurationProcessor ="org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:${BuildConstants.springBootVersion}"

    kapt(configurationProcessor) // for jar
    kaptTest(configurationProcessor) // for jar
    annotationProcessor(configurationProcessor) // for IntelliJ Idea
}

/* ... */

kapt {
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor")
}

/* ... */

tasks {
    withType<KotlinCompile> {
        dependsOn(processResources)
    }
}
```

Kotlin Kapt is needed to work with metadata and memory.

From [official Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-configuration-metadata.html), Spring Boot Configuration Processor generates special json file with properties metadata.

Therefore, to distribute `jar` with property syntax highlight you need:

- Ask Gradle to generate this file
- Update task sequence to generate file before `jar` packaging by using `dependsOn` (not sure, that my code above is the most effective solution, however problem is solved)

However IntelliJ Idea works with `annotationProcessor` Gradle configuration (unfortunately, I don't have exact answer, why it requires exact it). Therefore you need add the same processor into the `annotationProcessor` configuration as well.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I noticed a few things: 1. I only needed to add the dependencies, I didn't need to specify the annotation processor class in order for the files to be generated. 2. I didn't need `dependsOn(processResources)`, I couldn't even import `processResources` to begin with. 3. My IntelliJ IDEA doesn't complain if I leave out `annotationProcessor(configurationProcessor)`. Can you confirm these observations?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem plus not showing auto completion found out that it works with IntelliJ Ultimate edition and not community version. [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006882520-Java-Spring-application-properties-Code-Completion-not-working)

couple of useful steps to take would be:

- adding **Maven** dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

- refresh Maven to download dependencies.
- coping exact name of property from `target/classes/META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.js` to prevent errors.
- making sure that your config class is annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties("name-here")` and that you have enabled it by `@EnableConfigurationProperties(NameOfTheConfigClass.class)`

Answer (score 0):

A Gradle-based workaround is this:

```kotlin
afterEvaluate {
    val kaptKotlinTasks = tasks.named("kaptKotlin") {
        doLast {
            val kaptKotlin = this
            tasks.named<ProcessResources>("processResources") {
                from(kaptKotlin.outputs) {
                    include("META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    tasks.named("processResources") {
        this.dependsOn(kaptKotlinTasks)
    }
}
```

After running a build (or just the `processResources` task) from the Intellij Gradle panel, the warnings about the properties should disappear.

Not ideal, but IntelliJ not supporting kapt is not ideal either :-/

Answer (score 0):

As an additional requirement for the answers above. After Spring-boot 2.2 you can use `final` keyword on the attributes together with the annotation `@ConstructorBinding` in order to see IntelliJ auto-complete the property name on the `application.properties` file. IntelliJ also recognizes if you add a java docs on the attribute.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-config")
@ConstructorBinding
public class ConfigImportService {

    /**
     * the name of the bucket 
     * (IntelliJ shows this comment on the application.properties file)
     */
    private final String bucketName;
    private final String databaseName;

    @Autowired
    public ConfigImportService(
        @Value("${bucket.name}") String bucketName,
        @Value("${db.name}") String databaseName
    ) {
        this.bucketName = bucketName;
        this.databaseName = databaseName;
    }
}
```

And still necessary the dependency, of course.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Spring Voot 3**+ in application.properties u can use

```
spring.ldap.urls=192.168.1.1 #instead of spring.ldap.url
spring.ldap.base=dc=example,dc=com
spring.ldap.username=uid=admin,ou=system
spring.ldap.password=secret
```