# Proper way to fix IntelliJ IDEA warnings about unused properties from AWS sdk on spring boot application

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, intellij-idea, properties

I have a standard spring boot application that uses some AWS SDK modules.
Which AWS modules does not matter.

My problem is that the IDE warns me about unused props (they work fine), such as:

```
# AWS
aws.secretsmanager.prefix=foo
aws.secretsmanager.profileSeparator=/
aws.secretsmanager.fail-fast=true
```

.. but there are many more.

I found answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48954087/intellij-idea-complains-cannot-resolve-spring-boot-properties-but-they-work-fine) but it won't work for me because that would require "manual" management of all AWS props, names, types and so on.

My AWS docs search-foo come out empty.

Do you recommend anything, or should I just live with these warnings on the IDE and don't worry about it too much?

---

edit:

IDE version is:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-193.6911.18, built on March 17, 2020
```

Comment: what is the version of you IDE?

Comment: @Kootli, updated above