# Can't get Java see my custom YAML property in a Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

Why doesn't it work?

```yaml
gateway:
  servers:
    - local-server:
        url: https://localhost:${server.port}
        description: Api-Gateway-V2
  v1-prefix: /api/v1
```

```java
package by.afinny.apigateway.constant;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.servers.Server;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public final class GatewayMeta {
    @Value("${gateway.servers}")
    public List<Server> servers;
    @Value("${gateway.v1-prefix}")
    public String v1Prefix;
    public List<Server> servers() {
        return servers;
    }
    public String v1Prefix() {
        return v1Prefix;
    }
}
```

```java
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.annotations.OpenAPI31;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Server {
    private String url = null;
    private String description = null;
    private ServerVariables variables = null;
    private Map<String, Object> extensions = null;

    public Server() {
    }

// ...
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'gateway.servers' in value "${gateway.servers}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
```

I tried adding some "configuration processor" as a regular dependency as per [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48954087/intellij-idea-complains-cannot-resolve-spring-boot-properties-but-they-work-fine), but it didn't work (should I wrap it in some "processor" tags?)

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

I don't get any META-INF in my `target` after a build ([should I](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-271468/Cannot-resolve-configuration-property-with-custom-configuration-properties)?)

Spring Boot 3, Java 17

## UPD

I tried this

```java
package by.afinny.apigateway.constant;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.servers.Server;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "gateway")
public final class GatewayMeta {
    public List<Server> servers;
    public String v1Prefix;
    public List<Server> servers() {
        return servers;
    }
    public String v1Prefix() {
        return v1Prefix;
    }
}
```

```yaml
# notice the camel case
gateway:
  servers:
    - local-server:
        url: https://localhost:${server.port}
        description: Api-Gateway-V2
  v1Prefix: /api/v1
```

I get an exception. It's relatively detailed, but I still don't understand what I need to do. Update how?

```
ERROR 19960 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target [Bindable@2a484710 type = java.util.List<io.swagger.v3.oas.models.servers.Server>, value = 'none', annotations = array<Annotation>[[empty]], bindMethod = [null]] failed:

    Property: gateway.servers[0].local-server.description
    Value: "Api-Gateway-V2"
    Origin: class path resource [application-prod.yml] - 53:22
    Reason: The elements [gateway.servers[0].local-server.description,gateway.servers[0].local-server.url] were left unbound.
    Property: gateway.servers[0].local-server.url
    Value: "https://localhost:${server.port}"
    Origin: class path resource [application-prod.yml] - 52:14
    Reason: The elements [gateway.servers[0].local-server.description,gateway.servers[0].local-server.url] were left unbound.

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

I also included `@EnableConfigurationProperties` above my `@SpringBootApplication` class (I accidentally found it and decided to put it just in case)

I discovered it has to do with `Server` serialization: if I comment out everything related to servers, the prefix does get resolved. But why? `Server` does have getters and setters

Besides, I don't want my yaml to be forced to follow that camel case. I haven't found some equivalent of `@JsonProperty` for `@ConfigurationProperties` (like `@ConfigurationProperty` or something)

Comment: follow next one article about [spring-yaml-inject-map](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-inject-map)

Comment: @AndreiLisa can you check the update please?

Comment: Have you managed to fix it yet ? I am going to check it on my local and I will post an answer about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For managed complex list is suggested to use `ConfigurationProperties`. I think that is your yml structure wrong.

I replicated here the case https://github.com/sbernardo/spring-issues-examples/tree/main/sof-questions-77646394

Old yml:

```yaml
gateway:
  servers:
    - local-server:
        url: https://localhost:${server.port}
        description: Api-Gateway-V2
  v1Prefix: /api/v1
```

New yml:

```yaml
gateway:
  servers:
    - local-server:
      url: https://localhost:${server.port}
      description: Api-Gateway-V2
    - local-server:
      url: https://localhost2:${server.port}
      description: Api-Gateway-V3
  v1Prefix: /api/v1
```

As you can see there is a level that throw exception. Because in yaml you are define and array with `-` simbol with only `local-server` key and you are add another level on each object with fields `url` and `description` fields.

I think key `local-server` is useless and you can remove it.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Though I still get warnings like `Cannot resolve configuration property 'gateway.servers'` (even though the properties *are* resolved). Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In Spring, when using the `@Value` annotation with placeholders like `${gateway.servers}`, Spring expects these values to be available in the application's property sources, typically defined in `application.properties` or `application.yml`. In your case, it seems like the `${gateway.servers}` property is not being resolved.

If you hava another file you can include it in your `Pom.xml`

```xml
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${PATH-DIR}</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>${FILE-NAME}</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```